# SaveAs html without creating the subfolders with .xml files

Tags: html, vba, outlook, ms-office

I am trying to SaveAs all incoming emails as .html files but it creates a subfolder with each email.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub ShowMessage(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\"
Item.SaveAs path & Item.SenderName & ".htm", olHTML
End Sub
```

It gives me something like:
"joe.htm" and a folder call "joe_files" with "colorschememapping.xml" and "filelist.xml" as well as "themedata.thmx"

Is there a way to save as without these files?

In Word I solved the problem by saving as Filtered HTML but it does not seem to be possible with Outlook.

Here is my code in MSWord:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=Path, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML
```

Or could it be possible to use the MailItem.BodyFormat to edit the item's body and then save it as html? That way we won't have all the automatic encoding of Outlook when it saves as HTML. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869979.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind... I solved it.
By re-reading my question I just realized that the answer was right there.

```
item.SaveAs path & Item.SenderName & ".htm", olTxt
```

Somehow the support page of Microsoft does not mention that Filtered HTML works on their code but it actually does.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868727.aspx?

Comment: olFilteredHTML? Did you get that enum from?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, yes that works as I wanted. It does not save the additional files.

Comment: What is olFilteredHTML? Where did it come from? It is definitely not one of the OlSaveAsType enum values. Did you declare olFilteredHTML in your code?

Comment: It works on MSWord so I tried it out on Outlook and he turned out working, so I am happy. It's that simple.

Comment: Word? MailItem.SaveAs is an Outlook method call, not Word. What does MsgBox(olFilteredHTML) display?

Comment: It seems like we're not understanding each other. On MS Word I had done this earlier: ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=Path, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML and that works. So now I tried Item.SaveAs path & Item.SenderName & ".htm", olFilteredHTML on MS Outlook and it also worked. It saves an .htm file without additional particles (it actually looks like a .txt file with the .htm extension instead of .txt).

Comment: Since  olFilteredHTML is not defined, it defaults to 0 when MailItem.SaveAs is called. And 0 is olTxt. You get a plain old text file.

Comment: That's right @DmitryStreblechenko I've just cross checked and it's defined by 0. I did not even notice before. I guess it's better to simply write olTxt then. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use olMHTML (10) format instead.

You can also simply read the `HTMLBody` property and save it as file - the problem might be Unicode characters - `HTMLBody` property is UTF-16, and an HTML file has to be 8 byte, so you need to convert it appropriately based on the value of the `PR_INTERNET_CPID` (which might not necessarily match the code page in the HTML body).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), it supports the `olHTMLEmbeddedImages` format it creates an HTML file with the image data inside the `<img>` tags. Outlook (which uses Word to render HTML message) does not like that, but both IE and Firefox should be fine. It embeds both the images already attached to the message as well as referenced images (which are downloaded):

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Item = Session.GetMessageFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)
  Item.SaveAs "c:\temp\HTMLWithImages.html", 1033 ' olHTMLEmbeddedImages
```

Comment: Which, just like an HTML file, can be displayed by IE. But it gives you a single file.

Comment: Yes, that's correct for i.e. but I am using Firefox and it did not look good on that. And the code of the file was extremely complicated. Tks anyhow.